# Import file as Javascript string

Tags: javascript, import, build, resources, asset-pipeline

I have a long string that, due to its complex generation process, needs to go to a static file.  I'd like to import it as a string variable, akin to:

```
// res.txt
The quick brown fox...

// code.js
import {res as String} from 'res.txt';
console.log(res); // Outputs: The quick brown fox...
```

This used to be doable via raw-loaders, but those seem to be deprecated in favor of more modern methods.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

import text file in java-script, java-script is not able import the file , to get text file you need to fetch that file , i attached the fetch API code here but it's not work here because of Cross-Origin Resource Sharing  policy error , so to resolve your error i suggest use fetch.

```js
      try {
        fetch(
          "https://example-files.online-convert.com/document/txt/example.txt"
        )
          .then((response) => response.text())
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
```

Comment: I don't want to fetch it live at _run time_, I wish to bundle it in at _build time_

Comment: So , with only java-script it is not possible. you must have to add `webpack` and add `raw-loader` package using npm after that it is possible